# How to transform first four rows of dataframe to column names without using loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the CSV-file and I need to combine its first four rows to headers (and first header needs to be empty). I tried to do that with Pandas and code works but I know that looping through dataframe is not recommended. Is there better way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
df_headers = df[0:4]
df = df.drop(index=[0,1,2,3,])
header_list = []

for column in df_headers:
    header_list.append(df_headers[column].str.cat(sep=' '))

header_list[0] = ""
df.columns = header_list

df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df
    0      1    2         3           4
0  id   name  tag  location        date
1   1   John   34        FL  1990-01-12
2   1  Peter   32        NC  1990-01-12
3   1   Dave   66        SC  1990-11-25
4   1   Mary   12        CA  1990-03-09
5   1    Sue   29        NY  1990-07-10
6   1    Eve   89        MA  1990-06-12
7   n   John   34        FL  2000-01-12
8   n  Peter   32        NC  2000-01-12
```

Your code:

```py
>>> df_headers = df[0:4]
>>> df = df.drop(index=[0,1,2,3,])
>>> header_list = []
>>> for column in df_headers:
...     header_list.append(df_headers[column].str.cat(sep=' '))
>>> header_list[0] = ""
>>> df.columns = header_list
>>> df
     name John Peter Dave tag 34 32 66 location FL NC SC date 1990-01-12 1990-01-12 1990-11-25
4  1                 Mary           12                CA                            1990-03-09
5  1                  Sue           29                NY                            1990-07-10
6  1                  Eve           89                MA                            1990-06-12
7  n                 John           34                FL                            2000-01-12
8  n                Peter           32                NC                            2000-01-12
```

New soluton:

```py
>>> columns_mapping = dict(zip(range(df.shape[1]), df.iloc[:4].astype(str).apply(' '.join).to_list()))
>>> df = df.iloc[4:].rename(columns=columns_mapping)
>>> df.columns = [''] + df.columns[1:].to_list()
>>> df
     name John Peter Dave tag 34 32 66 location FL NC SC date 1990-01-12 1990-01-12 1990-11-25
4  1                 Mary           12                CA                            1990-03-09
5  1                  Sue           29                NY                            1990-07-10
6  1                  Eve           89                MA                            1990-06-12
7  n                 John           34                FL                            2000-01-12
8  n                Peter           32                NC                            2000-01-12
```

Comment: @procrastinator This is actually an answer to the question. If you think it is not a *good* one - downvote it, don't vote to delete something that tries, however badly, to answer the question. Please read [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/6045800)

Comment: @procrastinator It's provide an answer, It does the same job, with no looping.

Comment: @procrastinator I have added the code output with data, new tell me how it does not provide a solution.